# use of "said fiercely"

Tags: adverbs

> 'How can you stand this? he asked Hermione fiercely. 'Just standing
> here and watching it happen?' He hesitated. 'I'm going to grab the
> Cloak!'

Context: Harry and Hermione have gone back in time. Harry really wants to interfere and save Black. But Hermione doesn't want Harry to change something drastic.

1. Now, Does "said fiercely" mean "in an angry way" or "with a heartfelt and powerful intensity"?
2. And does it always, in almost all contexts, mean said angrily?

Comment: Does Harry seem calm or intense? When a word has different defintions, it is unlikely to mean them all at the same time.

Comment: fiercely is the opposite of gently.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you got these two meanings of *fiercely* by looking it up (if so, thank you!). But when I try, I don't find any mention of anger in the [first](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiercely) [four](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fiercely) [dictionaries](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fiercely) [I've](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fiercely) tried. Many mention intensity and forcefulness.

> Does "said fiercely" mean "in an angry way" or "with a heartfelt and powerful intensity"?

Can it not be both? I would argue that intensity is always integral to fierceness—you can't really be "mildly fierce." But you could put that emotional intensity behind any of several emotions. Yes, you could be angry "with a heartfelt and powerful intensity."

> And does it always, in almost all contexts, mean said angrily?

As is hopefully clear by now, no. One can be fiercely happy, fiercely determined, even fiercely independent.

So how do you tell? As always, context. Is Harry angry in this passage?